# Why does it take so long for cpu to write memory after it has obtained the physical address?

Tags: linux-kernel, tlb, mmu

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/6ce64428d62026a10cb5d80138ff2f90cc21d367:

```
cpu0                cpu1            cpu2
----                ----            ----
                            [ Writable PTE
                              cached in TLB ]
userfaultfd_writeprotect()
[ write-*unprotect* ]
mwriteprotect_range()
mmap_read_lock()
change_protection()

change_protection_range()
...
change_pte_range()
[ *clear* “write”-bit ]
[ defer TLB flushes ]
                [ page-fault ]
                ...
                wp_page_copy()
                 cow_user_page()
                  [ copy page ]
                            [ write to old
                              page ]
                ...
                 set_pte_at_notify()
```

I think cpu2 spends too long just only a store instrution.Can store instrution be interrupted?

I have looked up a lot of things that need to be done on the hardware to access the memory after getting the physical address, such as checking the cache, but will these take that long?

Comment: These are steps need to write a 'COW' (copy on write) page.  It is specific to linux.  An OS does not need to implement 'COW'.  Also, it happens on the first write of a page (4kB), so it is not happening on all accesses.  Also, this particular instance relates to updating the MMU structures and how they relate between CPUs.  The title of this question is either highly misleading or you have mis-understood the issue.  Also, nothing seems ARM specific.

Comment: I think you are simply interpreting the diagram the wrong way. CPU 2 does a write after CPU 1 does copy page. There is no indication anywhere about how long that write took. Just that it happens after copy page of CPU 1. The PTE could be cached in TLB by CPU 2 one billion instructions before the write.